# Return value based on event in python

Tags: python

I need to get the value calculated by the calculate function which is being called once event is being fired to on_release function. The value is to be outside the class.

```
class Annotate(object):
    def __init__(self,diff):
        self.differnce = diff
        self.x0 = None
        self.y0 = None
        self.x1 = None
        self.y1 = None
        self.ax = plt.gca()
        self.ax.figure.canvas.mpl_connect('button_press_event', self.on_press)
        self.ax.figure.canvas.mpl_connect('button_release_event', self.on_release)

    def on_press(self, event):
        print 'press'
        self.x0 = event.xdata
        self.y0 = event.ydata
        # return x0,y0

    def on_release(self, event):
        print 'release'
        x1 = event.xdata
        y1 = event.ydata
        self.calculate(int(self.x0), int(self.y0), int(x1), int(y1))

    def calculate(self, a, b, c, d):
        print a, b, c, d
        print self.differnce
        sum = 0
        count = 0
        for i in range(a, c):
            for j in range(b, d):
                sum = sum + self.differnce[i,j]
                count = count+1
        print sum
        print count
        if (sum==0):
            if(count==0):
                print "Try again"
        else:
            return sum/count

a = Annotate(diff)
print a
```

Comment: `return self.calculate(...)` and get the returned value.

Comment: What is `diff`? Your `Annotate` class does not accept any parameters

Comment: Do you have a constructor __init__(self, ...)?  Self.difference is never defined in the above code

Comment: @Jeon so how can I access it as variable?

Comment: Ah, I got your point. How about writing a value into a global variable? That's sometimes considered as bad...

Comment: Yeah that's the only possible solution?

Comment: I fixed your indentation, I believe.

Comment: Possible solution. Make a relationship between your class with another. Inside a on_realease, call another class' function that assigns value to variable and so on.

Comment: The class gets the variable as None

Comment: Can I make call to some function based on some function call ?